# Downloading image to apply as a Texture fails

Tags: unity, c#

In my app I need to download some images and apply them as Textures.

If I use following code to get image from my local pc hard disk, it works.

But it does not work if I use a url like (http://www.something.com/image.jpg). In that case, the texture appears as the image below.

More specifically:

1. The image I'm downloading is not the one I've attached.
2. The image/url exists and is accessible
3. The image is a JPG
4. Loading the same image stored on my local pc works ( file:// instead of http:// )

   ```
   Texture2D tex;
   tex = new Texture2D(4, 4, TextureFormat.DXT1, false);
   if (url.Substring(0, 4).ToLower() != "http")
       url = "file://" + url;
   using (WWW www = new WWW(url))
   {
       www.LoadImageIntoTexture(tex);

       while (!www.isDone) { }
       if (www.error==null)
       {

           MyObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = (Texture)tex;
       }

   }
   ```

[image: Screenshot of error]

Comment: What do you mean by not working?  Do you get an error, is the texture null?  Have you tried debugging that line in your IDE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to load the downloaded data into your texture before you've waited for it to download:

```
using (WWW www = new WWW(url))
{
    // We've only just sent the request, and maybe haven't received a reply yet.
    // So here the downloaded data might still be empty or incomplete.
    www.LoadImageIntoTexture(tex);

    // Now we're finally giving the download a chance to finish and guarding against errors.
    while (!www.isDone) { }

    if (www.error==null)
    {    
        MyObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = (Texture)tex;
    }    
}
```

On your local file system, this may be so fast and error-free that the data is already reliably available then. On the web, where everything takes longer, you might have longer to wait before the data is ready.

Have you tried moving the `www.LoadImageIntoTexture(tex);` line down, so it's the first thing inside the `if (www.error == null) {...` block? This will delay the texture load until you're actually sure the download has finished without errors.